# a)Why doesn't the buble sort loop below work with randon.randint? b) Why does loop to count repeated items gets messy with random.randint?

Tags: python

I want to bubble sort a set of numbers with a for loop (see below). Ascending order works perfectly fine when I give N values, however it does not work if I use random.randint to create random numbers. Code still works but ignores loop all together. Why? and how can I fix it?

The second smaller loop is meant to count repeated items - again it works fine with a pre-set N array -It will still work with random but order gets messy. Why? and how can I fix it?

I would like to use plt.bar() to plot bars for this. Would it be possible to set randon.randint to a size 10 sampling from 1000 different numbers and plot it? It only works if all my arrays are the same size and randonrandint is np.random.randint(10, size=10)[same size for sampling and numbers]

```
result=[0]*10
#N= [1,7,5,4,7,7,1,4,4]
#N = np.random.randint(1,1000,10)

N=np.random.randint(10, size=10)

#N=np.random.randint(1000, size=10)

for i in range(len(N)):
 swapped = True
 count = swaps = 0
 count = 0
while swapped:
 count += 1
 swapped = False
 for i in range(1, len(N)-1):
  if N[i]>N[i+1]:
   temp = N[i]
   N[i] = N[i+1]
   N[i+1] = temp
   #swaps += 1
   swapped = True

print N

for i in N:
 result[i] += 1
```

Comment: Your indentation is totally off, it's hard to tell what your code is supposed to look like.

Comment: @BrenBarn beat me to it. The code provided is at best ambiguous.

Comment: I have changed it. Is it better?

Comment: Not really. Use 4 spaces for each indentation level.

Comment: I used ctrl-t --as suggested by the website

Comment: How could `N = np.random.randint(1,1000,10)` possibly work?`result[i] += 1` would potentially try to index  the array at index `1000` and you only have `10` items in the array? If you are sorting your inner loop should also be `for i in range(len(N) - 1):`

Comment: If you want to add 1 to each value use `N += 1`

Comment: Padraic, I used np.random.randing(1,1000,10) because I wanted ten numbers drawn out of 1000. Its fine if result[i] +=1 index to 1000, i don't think it changes what I want to do. Even if I use 
N=np.random.randint(10, size=10) - "print N" after loop is still out of order. I tried the for i in range(len(N) - 1): for the outer for loop as well but not much difference. Thank you for your reply

Comment: The only way I could get an array not sorted correctly would be to not use `for i in range(len(N) - 1):` because you would be ignoring the first element, `N = np.random.randint(1,1000,10)` works every time for me,  is `result[i] +=1`  relevant at all?

Comment: Not sure if I am getting what you are saying. I already have (len(N)-1) on the inner loop--

Comment: @user5144102, what I was saying is exactly the same as the answer you accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seemed to almost work for me except it was failing to sort the first entry. This was because your `range` started from 1 not 0:

```
import numpy as np

N=np.random.randint(10, size=10)
print N

for i in range(len(N)):
    swapped = True
    count = swaps = 0
    count = 0

    while swapped:
        count += 1
        swapped = False
        for i in range(0, len(N)-1):
            if N[i]>N[i+1]:
                temp = N[i]
                N[i] = N[i+1]
                N[i+1] = temp
                #swaps += 1
                swapped = True

print N

# Add one to all elements in numpy array

N += 1
print N
```

Gives the following possible output:

```
[0 6 6 0 6 3 7 8 7 6]
[0 0 3 6 6 6 6 7 7 8]
[1 1 4 7 7 7 7 8 8 9]
```